# Counting sort technique not working for me. Runtime Error Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

Tags: runtime-error, c++14, sigabrt, counting-sort

The given question is to sort an array of 0s, 1s and 2s. I decided to use the following counting sort technique for solving it.

```
void sort012(int a[], int n)
{
    int i,count[3];

    memset(count,0,sizeof(count));

    for(i=0; i<n ; i++)
        ++count[a[i]];

    for(i=1; i<3; i++)
        count[i] += count[i-1];

    for(i=n-1; i>=1; i--)
        count[i] = count[i-1];
    count[0] = 0;

    int output[n+1];

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        output[count[a[i]]]= a[i];
        ++count[a[i]];
    }

    for (i = 0; i<n; ++i)  
        a[i] = output[i]; 
}
```

Few test cases passed in this algorithm. But when I tried to submit it on Geeksforgeeks portal it displayed Runtime error: Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

Comment: `for(i=n-1; i>=1; i--) count[i] = count[i-1];` This exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds, whenever `n > 3`. What was that loop supposed to achieve? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I didn't get how it will exhibit undefined behaviour? The purpose of this loop is to shift elements to the right by 1 place.

Comment: The only valid indexes into `count` are 0, 1 and 2. This loop accesses `count[n-1]`, which is out of bounds whenever `n > 3`